# Search in array and insert values

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this one:

```
> Array
> (
>>    [trilha] => 1
>>    [0] => Array
>>>        (
>>>            [trilha] => 1,5
>>>            )
> )
```

and I want to cross with key TRILHA, inserting associated values:

```
> Array
> (
>> [1] => A 
>> [1,5] => B
>> [1,5,4] => C
> )
```

Is it possible?

The results should be:

```
> Array
> (
>>    [trilha] => 1
>>    [INSERTED] => A
>>    [0] => Array
>>>        (
>>>            [trilha] => 1,5
>>>            [INSERTED] => B
>>>            )
> )
```

I inserted the values from secondary array into first one.

Comment: I'm not at all sure what you're trying to do. Could you add what you expect the resulting array to look like?

Comment: Seconded. Also translating your indices and values to English would make it a lot clearer to us since we don't speak Portuguese (at least thats what it looks like to me)

Comment: Where is `A` (, `B`, `C`) and where is `1,5,4`?

Comment: @Erick: Ah, now it's more clear what you try to achieve. Question is, what did you try so far?

Comment: @hakre I created a recursive function but until now, its not reading the second-level array (key [0])...

Comment: If you add some real arrays (as in code), it would be easier to write something up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some working example, stack based recursive iteration and modification with PHP variable aliasing:

```
// to be modified:
$base = array(
    'trilha' => '1',
    array(
        'trilha' => '1,5',
    ),
);

// data for modification, binding value is key
$insert = Array(
    1 => 'A',
    '1,5' => 'B',
    '1,5,4' => 'C',
);

/*
 * stack based traversal and modifcation
 */
$stack = array();
$stack[] = &$base;
$first = 0;
while ($stack)
{
    $proc = & $stack[$first];
    unset($stack[$first++]);

    foreach ($proc as &$val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $stack[] = &$val;
        }
    }

    if (!isset($proc['trilha'])) {
        continue;
    }
    $trilha = $proc['trilha'];
    if (!isset($insert[$trilha])) {
        continue;
    }
    $proc['INSERTED'] = $insert[$trilha];
}
unset($proc);

var_dump($base);
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to clearly see some other interesting ways to solve the problem!!

Comment: @Erick: That's also "recursive" but only by traversing (so no recursive function calls). The part of inserting should be placed below the `foreach` as I see it, will update the answer.